# using relative URLs in nodejs express

Tags: node.js, url, express, routes

I am using express routing like:

```
router.get('/test', function(req, res, next) {
    if (user logged in)
        res.render('test');
    else res.redirect('login')
```

I'm rendering an EJS template file that has CSS links in it and URLs that are 
relative to this.
So you might see stuff like this in the test.ejs template:

```
 <link href = "../stylesheets/bootstrap.min.css" rel = "stylesheet">
 <a href="blee">blee</a>
```

The problem I encounter is that this route handler accepts URLs that look like

/test and /test/  -  This second URL causes my relative URLs to form incorrect absolute URLs. 
So if the URLs in my app (when deployed to production using Apache to forward to myapp) are:

```
example.com/myapp/test
```

I expect that the CSS be found at

```
example.com/myapp/stylesheets/bootstrap.min.css
```

and the blee URL found at

```
example.com/myapp/blee
```

and the redirect should go to

```
example.com/myapp/login
```

This works as long as the URL coming into the handler is /test

If, however, it is /test/ , the handler accepts it BUT the relative URLs formed are all incorrect.

My dev environment is different from my deploy environment so I can't code full URLs to things because its a longer path before /test.  Relative URLS just make better sense.

I've been told not to worry about the URL /test/  coming in as long as my app doesn't create it.  But sometimes a user types something into the location box and it sucks that if they type this, it lands inside this handler and generates a broken page.

Comment: Do you really need to use relative URLs in your web pages?  That's a recipe for disaster because you can't use common pieces of HTML unless they all sit at the same level of the file hierarchy.  Why not just put all your style sheets at an absolute URL location, make your express server respond to those routes and you're done.  If you really want to use relative URLs, then leave off the `../` part, but I don't recommend using relative URLs for common, shared resources.  They should live in an absolute location for your site.

Comment: OK.  I take your point.  I now generate absolute URLs which required taking apart the request URL and getting the parts of it I need (the host, port and part of the path).  I pass it in as a variable called pageContext to my EJS scripts and then prepend pageContext to all the URLs in the page I generate.  (There was a slight glitch with this method because when Apache forwards to node with a reverse proxy it loses the orginal URL and replaces with with localhost .   Had to use ProxyPreserveHost On to fix this)  .   JSP pageContext is a similar notion.

Comment: You should not have to manufacture URLs like this in your page.  If you just use a URL that starts with a forward `/`, then it will automatically be relative to your host and port.  So, if the domain of your page is `http://example.com` and you have a URL in the page that is `/styles/main.css`, then the browser will automatically make a request from `http://example.com/styles/main.css`.  You don't have to do that manually.  For example `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/styles/main.css">`.  This is relative to the page's domain, but absolute from a path perspective.

Comment: Huh?  a URL beginning with / is relative.   That's what your original response said to avoid.   My post is about the pitfalls of relative URLs when node is running behind a reverse proxy in Apache.  Because you have to tell Apache that a path like /myapp must be forwarded to node, paths all look like example.com/myapp.   So let's say you want to use / to generate a relative URL to /foo.   This would resolve to example.com/foo and not example.com/myapp/foo  .   /myapp is necessary for apache but the node app shouldn't have to know about it.

Comment: path relative is generally  to be avoided.  Domain relative (with leading slash) is generally desirable.